# Where did the k of $a_k$ disappear from Fourier Reverse Transform if $\omega=\omega_0k$?

Tags: fourier-transform, continuous-signals, fourier-series

> Where did the $k$ of $a_k$ disappear from Fourier Reverse Transform if $\omega=\omega_0k$?

We turn $\omega0$ to be $d\omega$, but $\omega=\omega_0k$, so shouldn’t there be a $k$ in the reverse transform?

Attached reference below:
[image]

Answer (score 3):

It is because $\omega_o$ approaches 0 such that $k\omega_o$ becomes a continuous function.

So the discrete function $X(jk\omega_o)$ becomes the continuous function $X(j\omega)$.

This is intuitive if you consider the Fourier Series expansion in that each component of the spectrum is spaced in frequency by $1/T$ Hz, (or $\omega_o = 2\pi/T$ radians/sec). Each of these components are given as $k\omega_o$ with $k$ being the set of all integers. So as $T$ gets larger, $1/T$ gets smaller, and hence $\omega_o$ gets smaller and as $T$ approaches infinity, $k \omega_o$ approaches a continuous function.

The concept behind the Fourier Series Expansion is that any continuous time function defined over time duration $T$ can be decomposed into a sum of sinusoids that each have a fundamental period of $T$ and all higher harmonics such that there are an integer number of cycles in $T$, the the waveform can repeat for all time and start and end the same way at all boundaries $t= NT$ for all integers $N$. For this reason no other frequency components can exist and the non-zero frequency spectrum is therefore discrete.

[image: Fourier Series Expansion]

The Fourier Series Expansion given above in terms of sines and cosines is much more compact using exponential frequency notation (and ultimately much more intuitive once you understand that $e^{j\Omega t}$ is a phasor rotating counter-clockwise on the complex plane at rate $\Omega$ radians per second) :

$$x(t) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}c_n e^{jn\Omega_o t}$$
Where

$e^{jn\Omega_o t} = \cos(n\Omega_o t) + j\sin(n\Omega_o t)$

$c_n = a_n - jb_n$

And $\Omega_o$ was used in place of $\omega_o$ just to match the plots I already had (where I was distinguishing radian frequency between analog and digital domains).

This becomes the Fourier Transform when we all $T$ to extend to infinity: the spacing given by $1/T$ between each of the components goes to zero, and the frequency spectrum therefore becomes continuous.

[image: Fourier Transform]

An easy way to observe this effect is by simply zero-padding a time domain waveform prior to taking the FFT: as you add more zeros, meaning $T$ gets larger, more and more samples will be interpolated in frequency as the spectrum approaches a continuous function.

Comment: Thanks Dan, I’ll need to go over it and think about what you said. (The first 2 lines)

Comment: @VitaliPom I added a picture, hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks you rock! I’ll need some time to go over it. Many thanks :)

Comment: @VitaliPom I added some more details if it was still confusing.

Comment: Hi I didn’t forget to mark the answer, I just was very confused about it and I really need a little bit more time to understand. But I didn’t forget. Just mentioning I’m confused on too many things and trying to get out of the mess. I mark and accept all the answers to each of my questions eventually.

Comment: @VitaliPom Oh no worries! Maybe it's a big step and you need to start with a new quesiton on the core things you are confused about.

Comment: OK, caught you up in the last question. Will arrive here soon as well. :’D

Answer (score 2):

In the first line they're showing that

$$Ta_k=X(jk\omega_0)\tag{1}$$

That's what they use in the second line, where they also use

$$\frac{1}{T}=\frac{\omega_0}{2\pi}\tag{2}$$

Note that the sum

$$\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}X(jk\omega_0)e^{jk\omega_0t}\omega_0\tag{3}$$

is a [Riemann sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sum) which converges to the integral of the inverse Fourier transform:

$$\lim_{\omega_0\to 0}\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}X(jk\omega_0)e^{jk\omega_0t}\omega_0=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}X(j\omega)e^{j\omega t}d\omega\tag{4}$$

Comment: Yes, but when integrating they’re looking at $d\omega$ not at $dT$. How can dw0 turn into dw...?

Comment: @VitaliPom: $\omega_0$ is the "step size" in the sum (note the $k\omega_0$ in the function). As $T$ is increased, $\omega_0$ becomes smaller and the (Riemann) sum becomes an integral with infinitesimal $d\omega$.

Comment: But isn’t it like doing to Ct dt and getting C? Alas differentiating constant multiplied by some t by t and getting the constant as a result.....?

Comment: @VitaliPom: We're not differentiating, but integrating. It's a Riemann sum, which converges to the integral as the step size goes to zero.

Comment: You’re right in differentiation we divide by dt, not multiply. (Regarding Reimann I remember). I’ll think a little bit more about it. Thanks Matt!